# Windows updates uninstalled MS Office

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, uninstall

recently, I installed *Microsoft Office 2013*, which seemed to be corrupt. However, I decided to uninstall it and thought there wouldn't be any problems.
But as I checked the updates, *Windows* lists up over 30 updates — for *Microsoft Office*!
I already checked `c:\windows\installer\`, where I uninstalled every package named like this (also in the `topic`-section) whee every packet has been deleted automatically after I uninstalled it — except the main package (`64b0b.msi` — `Microsoft Office 2013 Professional Plus`).
Anyway, why does Windows want to update a non-existent product?

Comment: Sounds like it's not completely uninstalled.  Try repairing the installation.

Comment: What do you mean by ‘repair’? which product? repair from the CD, which would install the whole stuff again, or am I wrong?

Comment: Repair Office the uninstall it since the first time it was "corrupt"…

Answer (score 2):

Try using http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/repair-office-programs-HA010357402.aspx this will properly remove the program.

Otherwise there are several other 3rd party programs that can remove it more thoroughly.

If the issue continues try contacting MS Office support via their forums. They are quite crap but the peer to peer help is very good.

Hope this helps